How Can I Achieve SVG Design with Canvas Performance in a React Application?
I'm developing a React application that needs to render a large number of elements. I've implemented the rendering using both  and .
Canvas: Provides excellent performance and smooth rendering.
SVG: Offers superior style and design capabilities with sharpness, but it lags in performance, resulting in some rendering lag.

I have already implemented several strategies to optimize rendering, such as:
Rendering elements only within the viewport.
Using useMemo to memoize static data.

My question is: How can I achieve the design and styling benefits of SVG while maintaining the high performance and smoothness of Canvas? Are there any advanced techniques or best practices that can help me bridge this gap?
Thank you for your assistance!
I tried to use a lot of basic method to achieve sharpness of SVG with canvas, but in final the SVG can't be replaced.

don't create large numbers of elements.

there are between like 150-500 elements

doesn't sound like a lot but if some of them are filters and/or masks or use elements or images then that could be a problem.

They are not images, the elements are candles, and a candle have 2 elements, wick and body, like  and . And I also have viewport render, and it render only 130 up to 500 base on scale from the 50k candles array. The performance is not that bad, but it is not comparable to canvas rendering

sure, that's its + point, if you want interactivity though then svg is the winner.

thanks for answers, I will find a method to use SVG with no lag
